# JS multidimentional array inside for loop

Tags: javascript

so, I have following js:

```
var INFO = [];
var newMap = {}; 
function user_info(id,name,url,img){          
    newMap[id] = [name, url, img];
    return newMap ;   
}

...

for (var j = 0; j < 2; j++) {   
    INFO.push(user_info(a,b,c,d));                                  
}                   
alert(JSON.stringify(INFO, null, 4));
```

Then, I get the following result:

[image]

I know why it is happening. Because `newMap` does not get emptied out before the second and third `for` loop run, and gets added multiple times.

Could someone help me with how to clean this or fix this issue so that there is only multiarray like below:

[image]

I tried to do the following:

```
var INFO = [];

function user_info(id,name,url,img){          
    var newMap = {}; 
    newMap[id] = [name, url, img];
    return newMap ;   
}
```

But getting the following result which is not what I am looking for:

[image]

Issue here is that all the actual arrays are inside of its own 2nd layer.

Comment: Instead of adding image, add the actual string, it's easy to add text than image.

Comment: What is `a`, `b`, `c`, `d`? Add complete code, also add live demo if possible.

Comment: It's  `"user_info(id,name,url,img)"` like shown in the `function`. I am not sure if this is relevant as the element in the array is not the question, but adding the array via for loop.  Thanks though.

Comment: Okay, try `function user_info(data) {
    for (loopoverdatahere) {
        newMap[id] = [name, url, img];
    }

    return newMap;
}

INFO.push(user_info(completeData));`. Send complete data to the function, it'll loop over all the data, add individual arrays inside object and return result.

Comment: Seems like all you really need is to get rid of the `INFO.push()` call inside the loop, and move it *after* the loop. The `user_info` doesn't need to return anything. https://jsfiddle.net/72ogoat5/

Comment: @squint Unfortunately there is a condition inside the loop which if true, calls the function.

Comment: @Tushar I am not fully understanding what this `loopoeverdatahere` and `completeData` is. I will try it again though. Thanks

Comment: @RyanPicard Now you understand why complete code is necessary to add in question. :). It is the data that you're looping over using `for` loop.

Comment: What's the point of the array if you are just wrapping one object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

like that:

```
function user_info(map, id,name,url,img){          
    map[id] = [name, url, img];
}

var INFO = [];
var newMap = {}; 
for (var j = 0; j < 2; j++) {   
    user_info(newMap, a,b,c,d)
}                   
INFO.push(newMap);

alert(JSON.stringify(INFO, null, 4));
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is all you need, although it's hard to test without access to what your j, a, b, c, d variables in your example:

```
var INFO = [],
    data = {};
for (var j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
    data[a] = [b, c, d];                               
}
INFO.push(data);           
alert(JSON.stringify(INFO, null, 4));
```